# Is it possible to make a pdf with different page size in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

If the size of the page is same, then no problem, but I need the page size should be the size of Image(which is variable),

```
void DgJpgToPdf::convertToPdf( const QStringList& theImagePathList, const QString& theOutputFileName )
{
    QPrinter printer;
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
    printer.setOutputFormat( QPrinter::PdfFormat );
    printer.setOutputFileName( theOutputFileName );
    QPainter painter;    
    painter.begin( &printer );
    //printer.newPage();
    foreach( QString  fileName, theImagePathList ){
        QImage imgObj( fileName );    
        printer.setPaperSize( QSizeF(imgObj.width(), imgObj.height()), QPrinter::DevicePixel );        
        painter.drawImage( 0, 0, imgObj );
        printer.newPage();
    }
    painter.end();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may wish to use [`QPdfWriter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpdfwriter.html) rather than `QPrinter`. You'll have to pick a PPI for the image, but if you want to save at 96 PPI, you could do something like

```
QPdfWriter pdfWriter(theOutputFileName);
pdfWriter.setTitle(theDocumentTitle);
pdfWriter.setCreater(yourApplicationName);

const qreal horizontalMarginMM = 2.0;     // 2mm margin on each side
const qreal verticalMarginMM = 2.0;
QPagedDevice::Margins margins;
margins.left = margins.right = horizontalMarginMM;
margins.top = margins.bottom = verticalMarginMM;
pdfWriter.setMargins(margins);

bool newPage = false;
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&pdfWriter);

foreach (const QString& fileName, theImagePathList) {
  QImage imageObj(fileName);

  if (newPage)
    pdfWriter.newPage();
  newPage = true;
  qreal pageWidthMM = imgObj.width() / 96.0 * 25.4 + 2*horizontalMarginMM;
  qreal pageHeightMM = imgObj.height() / 96.0 * 25.4 + 2*verticalMarginMM;

  imgObj.setDotsPerMeterX(96.0 / 25.4 * 1000.0);
  imgObj.setDotsPerMeterY(96.0 / 25.4 * 1000.0);

  pdfWriter.setPageSizeMM(QSizeF(pageWidthMM, pageHeightMM));
  painter.drawImage(0, 0, imageObj);
}
painter.end();
```