# Print different size pages - Determine if printer is pdf

Tags: qt, qprinter

**Problem:**

My project... printing a sequence of pages... created based on certain templates and database info...

The sequence of pages to be printed can be, in certain situations, of different sizes.

I have been trying to print to real printer, producing multiple pages

```
if (m_printer->newPage()) { ... }
```

and on a physical printer, if I try to change the page size, it either doesn't work or puts the printer in an error state.

So there is not much choice, it seems, but to make each page a separate job. Minor disadvantages - possibly on a network. Oh well.

On pdf or any type of file printing, though, it makes a huge difference, whether the sequence is contained in a single document on multiple pages, or if it creates hundreds of different documents of one page each.

So, I found this [Is it possible to make a pdf with different page size in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21265653/1217150)

it seems to be exactly what I need, if I print to a pdf - while for real printer I will make each page a separate job.

The only problem:

**How can I tell if I am creating a pdf file, or if I am sending a job to a real printer ?**

I looked in QPrinter and QPrinterInfo, I did not see anything that can help.

Pdf printing is probably enabled because of Adobe Acrobat.

I am implementing this currently in Windows.

**Edit:** why getting the outputFormat (Naidu's answer below) doesn't work:

```
qprinter.cpp:
void QPrinterPrivate::initEngines(QPrinter::OutputFormat format, const QPrinterInfo &printer)
{
    ..
    // Only set NativeFormat if we have a valid plugin and printer to use
    if (format == QPrinter::NativeFormat) {    //////// which of course has to be, we have to support any printer
        ps = QPlatformPrinterSupportPlugin::get();
        QPrinterInfo printerToUse = findValidPrinter(printer);
        if (ps && !printerToUse.isNull()) {    //////// both valid since the PDF writer is valid
            outputFormat = QPrinter::NativeFormat;
            printerName = printerToUse.printerName();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I would like to have something to check, other than the fact that "pdf" may be contained in the name. If needed, I am willing to use the awful DEVMODE, I just don't know what to look for.

Comment: Now to understand you better, if you leave your app aside and on your OS print a document to your PDF printer, then you get a file also , and if you generate the output by the example you linked .. you get also a file .. so is this what you want to know

Comment: @MohammadKanan What I need is: I try to print to the default printer - open the print dialog - the user selects a printer or uses the default - the application does not control what the user chooses. Did the user choose a physical printer or a pdf printer ? (After I know, I can implement either normal printing one page per job, or the linked example)

Comment: if the print dialog shown from your app, that means your code is assigning the printer based on user selection, which means you can catch user selection in your code ..

Comment: @MohammadKanan yes - I just don't know what should I be looking for. Printer name can be anything, even make-and-model is not something i can be sure of. and the output format doesn't seem to be set correctly by the pdf printer.

Comment: I have had this problem before, I agree its not clean. My solution was also not very clean: `if(availablePrinters.at(indexPrinter).availablePrinterNames().at(indexPrinter).contains("PDF"))`

Comment: This worked good for me on windows, because PDF printer is auto generated by the system and it always contains "pdf" in its name, I don't know on Linux

Comment: @MohammadKanan perhaps I will have to do that... I try to avoid names because can you be completely sure that a normal printer can not have in its name "pdf" ?

Comment: I didn't extend my digging beyond that, but you still can check  for the available printers `QPaintDevice::physicalDpiX()` , and `QPaintDevice::paintEngine()` .. I have a feeling you might get good enough differentiation based on one of these .. honestly I never tried

Comment: I am just guessing `QPaintDevice::physicalDpiX()` must be undefined for PDF printer ..

Comment: @MohammadKanan Actually... It is kind of awesome: 1200

Comment: hmm not really what you want

Answer (score 3):

Use the public function

```
QPrinter::outputFormat()
```

it returns an enum type enum `QPrinter::OutputFormat`.

And check if it is `QPrinter::PdfFormat`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#OutputFormat-enum

Comment: even if the format is PDF , you can send it to real printer (not to file) isn't that true?

Comment: No I guess.... if no format specified (by default) or QPrinter::NativeFormat is specified the it goes to real printer...

Comment: I think if the selected printer is not a PDF printer but a real h/w then print job goes there regardless of format.

Comment: @Naidu I just tried - I selected the PDF from the print dialog and debug printed `m_printer->outputFormat() << QPrinter::PdfFormat` and I got `0 1`... So this may be only valid for the native (Linux) pdf print.