# Unable to add new pages in pdf file using QPdfWriter

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF file with multiple pages (using Qt 6.2.0 with MinGW 64 bit on Windows 10).

Using the following code, all calls to `QPdfWriter::newPage` fail:

```
QFile outputFile(filename);
if (!outputFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    return;

QPdfWriter writer(&outputFile);
writer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A5));
writer.setPageOrientation(QPageLayout::Landscape);

QPainter painter;

// First page
if (!writer.newPage())
    qWarning() << "newPage failed";
if (!painter.begin(&writer))
    qWarning() << "QPainter::begin failed";
QTextDocument page1;
page1.setHtml("<h1 align=center>Page 1</h1><p align=justify>Test page 1</p>");
page1.drawContents(&painter);
if (!painter.end())
    qWarning() << "QPainter::end failed";

// second page
if (!writer.newPage())
    qWarning() << "newPage failed";
if (!painter.begin(&writer))
    qWarning() << "QPainter::begin failed";
QTextDocument page2;
page2.setHtml("<h1 align=center>Page 2</h1><p align=justify>Test page 2</p>");
page2.drawContents(&painter);
if (!painter.end())
    qWarning() << "QPainter::end failed";
```

This code just generates a PDF file with a single page (only the content of my second page). All calls to `QPdfWriter::newPage` fail, all other calls seem to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're repainting over your first page when you end your painter and start it again for the 2nd page, you should start at the start of your pdf file, and end it at its end.

Here's an example:

```
QPdfWriter writer("test.pdf");
writer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A7));
writer.setPageOrientation(QPageLayout::Landscape);

QPainter painter;

// First page
if (!painter.begin(&writer))
   qWarning() << "QPainter::begin failed";
QTextDocument page1;
page1.setHtml("<h1 style=\"color: red\" align=center>Page 1</h1><p style=\"color: red\" align=justify>Test page 1</p>");
page1.drawContents(&painter);

// second page
if (!writer.newPage())
   qWarning() << "newPage failed";
QTextDocument page2;
page2.setHtml("<h1 style=\"color: red\" align=center>Page 2</h1><p style=\"color: red\" align=justify>Test page 2</p>");
page2.drawContents(&painter);
if (!painter.end())
   qWarning() << "QPainter::end failed";
```

Also, no need for a new page before the first page, you'll end up creating an empty page before it.

Here's where I got the idea: [Is it possible to make a pdf with different page size in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21265653/17726418)